# Django raw sql with datetime

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I use postgres for my django project, and for complicated queries to db i use connection.cursor(). Today I have a problem with raw sql query with datetime in filter:

```
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:

        cursor.execute(
            "SELECT * from orders_orderstatus WHERE datetime > '2017-09-05 16:07:16'"
        )
        row = [item[0] for item in cursor.fetchall()]
    return row
```

As result we have empty list. But if I query this from psql console, I see that result is not empty:

```
SELECT * FROM orders_orderstatus WHERE datetime > '2017-09-05 16:07:16';

id  |       status       |           datetime            
----+--------------------+-------------------------------+
256 | created    | 2017-09-05 16:10:59.602091+07
257 | delivered  | 2017-09-05 16:11:00.834547+07 
258 | created    | 2017-09-05 16:11:03.499364+07
```

Why django doesn't receive this results?

Comment: Bypassing Django's ORM can be tricky. In many cases it is better to stick with building `QuerySet`s; the query shown above can easily be executed using that way.

Comment: In any case, [two connections to PostgreSQL may see different data](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc-intro.html). This is [a feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control). Do you use transactions with your manual queries? Without more information it's hard to know if that's what's happening here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is show your how python and psql interpret datetime's strings tzinfo.

psql using your string time as UTC.
python send it to db with +hours_of_your_time_zone

If your tz +07 so try in python:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:

    cursor.execute(
        "SELECT * from orders_orderstatus WHERE datetime > '2017-09-05 09:07:16'"
    )
    row = [item[0] for item in cursor.fetchall()]
return row
```

In future try to use datetime objects with tz.

Looks like you have setting:

```
USE_TZ=True
```